# Tangent space of affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety, and let  and $p \in X$ be a point.
A line $\ell \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is said to be tangent to $X$ at $p$, if the intersection multiplicity $i_p(X \cap \ell)$ is at least 2.

Many authors define the tangent space $T_p X$ to  $X$ at $p$ as the : **"union of all the lines that are tangent to $X$ at $P$"**.

My question is:

How would one deal with the case $X=\{(0,0)\}\subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$?
As far as I can see, there is no tangent line at $p=(0,0)$,  at least not with the usual definition of tangent line stated above. Clearly, for this case, we should have $T_p X=\{p\}$. But reading this as the "union of all lines $\ell$ with $i_p(X \cap \ell) \geq 2$" sounds  bit strange for me.  Since I have never seen a warning regarding this case,
I'm wondering if I am missing something.

Comment: "Many authors define..." like who? I have never seen this before and it's a bad definition as you're pointing out.

Comment: Here are some sources. There are many others spread out online in lecture notes.

*Definitions 2 and 3 can be found on page 73 of Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry."
*Pages 185 and 186 of Ciro Ciliberto's "An Undergraduate Primer in Algebraic Geometry"

Comment: I think in this context the empty union of lines through $p$ should be $\{p\}$.